# The page number of a `hypertarget`

Tags: hyperref

To show the page number of a Figure or a Table, `\pageref` is useful. However, it does not work for a `\hypertarget`.

What if I need to show the page number of a hyper-target?

For example:

```
The problem is explained in page ???? at \hyperlink{my-explanation}{here}

.
.
.

\hypertarget{my-explanation}
Explanation ....
```

---

**Attempt:**

`\getpagerefnumber{my-explanation}` does not work and it returns zero.

Comment: You've asked several questions by now. Where is the MWE?

Answer (score 6):

Similar to `touhami`'s answer, but using the `phantomsection` and `\label` to get correct anchors, all combining into a `\pagetarget` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\pagetarget}[2]{%
  \phantomsection%
  \label{#1}%
  \hypertarget{#1}{#2}%
}


\begin{document}

The problem is explained in page \pageref{my-explanation} at \hyperlink{my-explanation}{here}

\blinddocument
\blindtext[2]
\pagetarget{my-explanation}{Explanation}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not even close. First, i used `mwe` ..., ... ;-)

Comment: @touhami: Which I never use ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\label-\pageref`.

**Example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

The problem is explained in page \pageref{my-explanation} at \hyperlink{my-explanation}{here}

\blinddocument

...
\hypertarget{my-explanation}{\label{my-explanation}Explanation} ....

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do `hypertarget` and `label` IDs collide?

Comment: If i understand, no, there is nothing between them.

Comment: I'm not sure that's safe. `\label` points in that case to the last counter increased by `\refstepcounter`, which is subsection 2.3.1 in your document. Try adding `\lipsum` between `\blinddocument` and `\hypertarget`: the `\hyperkink` and the page number will work, but clicking onto the page number will take you to the section, not to the point where you called `\label`. `\phantomsection` should be the way to go, I think.

Comment: @campa you're right. For me the question was *to show the page number* `\hyperkink` is there if you want go to the page. And again, your right use of `\phantomsection` is safer.

Comment: @touhami: You could use another counter that is increased with `\refstepcounter` and then `\label`, but effectively, this is the same as `\phantomsection`